# How to make multiclass classification with condition

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have .csv file looking like this:

| comment | toxicity |
| --- | --- |
| "toxic comment" | 0,6232 |
| "clean comment" | 0 |
| "another toxic comment" | 1 |

If "toxicity" value close to '1' that means comment is very toxic.

I want to do Multiclass Classification with this condition ;
**toxicity=0** and **toxicity!=0**
But I couldn't find how to apply this condition to classification.

I did something like that :

```
x= df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=df.iloc[:,1].values
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
x = le.fit_transform(x)
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3,algorithm='ball_tree')
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred3 = clf.predict(x_test)
acc3 = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred3)
```

But I am getting this error ;

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\hayyi.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 123, in 
> clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_classification.py",
> line 198, in fit
> return self._fit(X, y)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_base.py",
> line 400, in _fit
> X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse="csr", multi_output=True)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py",
> line 576, in _validate_data
> X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
> line 956, in check_X_y
> X = check_array(
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
> line 761, in check_array
> raise ValueError(
>
> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[1356040
> 918709  372428 ...  719104 1170089 1856713]. Reshape your data either
> using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or
> array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

And after that I try to do linear regression to splited datas like that ;

```
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,Y_train)
predict_test = reg.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(X_train,Y_train)
plt.plot(X_train,predict_test, color='red')
```

**Question 1**
How can I make multiclass classification with condition **toxicity=0** and **toxicity!=0** ?

**Question 2**
Is my linear regression code is wrong? I printed regression table but it seems very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I understood that you want to do binary classification so for that you have to convert your output variable into binary class like if the toxicity value is 0 then keep it 0 i.e non-toxic, and for value other than 0 convert it into 1 i.e toxic.

```
df['output'] = df['toxicity'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else 1)
```

Also, you need to convert your first column to numerical values otherwise Algorithm will not work on this data

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using label encoder for convert first column to numerical values. Is this right? And can you help me about why KNN code giving that error ?